# Laravel Airlock Token

Tags: laravel, http-token-authentication

## Introduction/Background

I'm looking to enable token authentication for multiple microservices and users. Both applications and users are `$user` objects.

I need to be able to authenticate once (hence token) using an auth server on a subdomain. I then need to be able to pass around a token that can be managed (revoked/refreshed whatever) by the Auth server.

The microservices are Laravel based, so using Airlock makes sense. Airlock generates tokens easily using:

- `$token = $user->createToken(now())`

However, I see no method to manually check the validity of these tokens... So I assumed they are available in the database.

Airlock suggests that the token be returned as follows:

- `$token->plainTextToken`

This produces a token, as expected. To my understanding, this is a public facing token. It does not match the token in the `personal_access_tokens` table.

Lets call these `PublicToken` and `PrivateToken`.

The private token is actually located in:

- `$token->accessToken->token`

I want to be able to manually switch between a PublicToken. I assume Airlock is doing some security here.. and I want to invoke these secure methods required to check a PublicToken against the PrivateToken.

Please do not say "it's in middleware" ... The point is that I have multiple microservices and usertypes sharing a database. I have an auth server that will end up on secure architecture, and some of the other microservices wont be.... fundamentally I need to do a manual authentication because normal plug and play wont work. Using Airlock as the foundation is great. But I need to be able to know how to convert between public and private tokens.

Essentially I'm looking for the real version of the following psuedocode:

- `if( someTranslationFunction($public_token) == $private_token ) ...`

## TLDR: The problem

How do I validate a `$token->plainText` value against a `$token` manually?

Comment: You may want to look into JWTs. I don't think Airlock is for you; it's explicitly described as "featherweight" and "simple", which your infrastructure - lots of microservices - doesn't sound like it matches.

Comment: I can't think of anything more "simple" than generate a token and be able to check it?

Comment: Like I said, look at JWTs. Airlock is stated to be simple auth for SPAs.